# Apache Spark input file being split an unnecessary number of times because of use in separate RDD

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to implement the Apriori algorithm (including Hash Trees) in Spark (v2.2.0) as part of some research I'm doing. I have reached a roadblock in my current implementation because of a restriction I believe is based on Spark.

**Problem:** 
I receive the correct answer from my implementation. However, it's taking far too long. When reading through the logs, I have massive amounts of the following lines:

```
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:55+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:0+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:55+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:0+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:0+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:55+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:0+55
17/12/01 08:47:11 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:example.txt:55+55
```

I have narrowed down the cause of this output spam to the following lines of code:

```
candidateSet.collect().forEach(itemset -> {
    tree.insert(itemset);
});
```

With my example.txt, I have 40 lines. The HadoopRDD: Input split occurs 80 times with this example.

I create the RDD as follows:

```
JavaRDD<String> inputLines = context.textFile(inputFileName);

    // Read in old itemset as a set of integers, with each integer referring to the ID of the item
    JavaRDD<Set<Integer>> inputItems = inputLines.map(
        new Function<String, Set<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public Set<Integer> call(String inputLine) throws Exception {
                Set<Integer> oldItemset = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                String[] itemsInLine = inputLine.split(" ");
                for(String item : itemsInLine) {
                    oldItemset.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
                }
                return oldItemset;
            }

        }
    );

    // Compute the cross product of the old itemset with itself, and only keep pairs where _1 < _2
    JavaPairRDD<Set<Integer>, Set<Integer>> candidateCrossProduct = inputItems.cartesian(inputItems).filter(
        new Function<Tuple2<Set<Integer>,Set<Integer>>,Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Tuple2<Set<Integer>, Set<Integer>> setPair) throws Exception {
                return isSetLessThanSet(setPair._1, setPair._2);
            }

        }
    );

    // Create candidate set by combining the two sets in the cross product and pruning all 
    //   itemsets that are not the size we are looking for in this iteration
    JavaRDD<Set<Integer>> candidateSet = candidateCrossProduct.map(
        new Function<Tuple2<Set<Integer>,Set<Integer>>,Set<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Set<Integer> call(Tuple2<Set<Integer>, Set<Integer>> itemsetTuple) throws Exception {
                Set<Integer> candidateItems = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                candidateItems.addAll(itemsetTuple._1());
                candidateItems.addAll(itemsetTuple._2());
                return candidateItems;
            }

        }
    ).filter(
        new Function<Set<Integer>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Set<Integer> itemset) throws Exception {
                return itemset.size() == itemsetCount;
            }
        }
    );
```

**What I believe the problem is:**
I could be misusing RDDs in some way to cause this text file to be opened twice for every line of input, but I am unsure of what I could be doing to cause such behavior. Is there something you see that truly stands out? 
The problem could also be due to my use of the HashTree in another RDD. After creating the HashTree, I query each line of a different input file against the HashTree to see if the HashTree contains an element of that line. I believe (and hope) this is less likely, because the number of input splits is due to size of the file that is fed in for the HashTree. However, if the future RDD's action that calls the HashTree is what triggers the collect, and the HashTree has to be re-generated every time it's called in the future RDD, that could be the cause. I truly hope this is not what's happening, as I don't see another possible way to implement the use of the HashTree in another RDD, having it contain data from a different file, without some intense HadoopRDD: Input splitting.

Thanks for your time.